# Graph from binary matrix (not adjacency) respecting the original matrix positions

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks, binary

[image: What to do]

I have a binary matrix. My objective is to connect every close (without "jump") elements with value equal to 1, but I must keep the point positions, just like it's shown at the image.

Can somebody help me with it, please?

Test input thanks to @hftf:

```
{{0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0},
 {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0},
 {0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},
 {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0}}
```

Comment: See if MorphologicalGraph is what you need.

Comment: Can you provide the matrix? :)

Comment: @Öskå `{{0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0}, {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0}, {0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0}, {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0}, {0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0}}`

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tryed to use MorphologicalGraph and SkeletonTransform. Both are not helping me to find a graph similar to the image above. But thanks for you help, @Szabolcs.

Comment: @Jazz In what way is the output of MorphologicalGraph incorrect?  (I'm trying to understand the question.)

Comment: [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tOxbt.png) is what I have.

Comment: Wow! It's really different from what I saw at the output. Let me check what I'm doing wrongly here. Looking at what you showed, I can say that I was wrong when I said that MorphologicalGraph is not helping.

Comment: @Öskå Could you, please, share the input you have used to get that output?

Comment: @Öskå yes, absolutely! And thanks for your help, guys.

Comment: @Szabolcs `ArrayPlot[m, Frame -> None] // ColorNegate // MorphologicalGraph` ... ;-)

Comment: @YvesKlett It doesnt really look good does it? :o

Comment: @Öskå not really, no. Yours is much to be preferred! :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
matOP = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
         {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}};
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
binaryGraph[mat_, col_] := Module[{pos, edge, dedge},
  pos = Position[mat, 1];
  edge = Select[Subsets[Range@Length@pos, {2}], 
    Last@# - First@# <= (Max@Dimensions@mat + 1) &]; 
  dedge = DeleteDuplicates[
    UndirectedEdge @@@ (Extract[edge, #] & /@ 
       With[{dist = N@(EuclideanDistance[pos[[#]], pos[[#2]]] & @@@ edge)}, 
        Flatten[Position[dist, #] & /@ 
          DeleteDuplicates@N@Select[dist, # <= Sqrt@2 &]]])];
  Graph[dedge, VertexCoordinates -> 
    Rule @@@ Thread[{Range@Length@pos, ({#2, -#1} & @@@ pos)}], 
    VertexStyle -> col, EdgeStyle -> col]]

arrayPlotGraph[mat_, graph_, sc_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 ArrayPlot[mat, Epilog -> 
   Inset[Show@graph, ImageScaled[{.5, .5}], 
     ImageScaled[{.5, .5}], ImageScaled@sc],
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ArrayPlot]]]]

g = binaryGraph[matOP, Hue@.6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
arrayPlotGraph[matOP, g, .88, ImageSize -> 350]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same can obviously be done with random matrices:

```
SeedRandom@0;
mat = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {20, 20}];
gg = binaryGraph[mat, Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
arrayPlotGraph[mat, gg, 1, ImageSize -> 350]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If anyone had an idea about how to make `ArrayPlot` and `Graph` perfectly overlay at the right position without using `ImageScaled@sc` and playing around with `sc` please let me know :)

---

Note that the process can be reversed (except that last *0-columns* and lonely *1* are lost):

```
rmat = SparseArray[# -> 1 & /@ 
  Rationalize /@ PropertyValue[g, VertexCoordinates]]
Row[MatrixPlot[#, ImageSize -> {200, 200}] & /@ {matOP, rmat}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It should be working for any matrices as well, just notify me if you have an issue.

Comment: @Öskå - so nice ! would there be a way to show that the outermost columns are empty?

Comment: @eldo I'm afraid not, or I don't see how right now..

Comment: @Öskå: +1, nice, concise answer.

Comment: @eldo How about now? I think it shows that the outermost columns are empty ;o)

Comment: @Öskå - That's what I wanted to see, thank you :)

Answer (score 14):

```
mtrx = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}};
```

Once we re-number the elements of `mtrx` using a function like

```
renumber = Module[{i = 1}, # /. 1 :> i++] &; (* thanks: Mr.W *)

mtrx2 =renumber@mtrx
```

**`ComponentMeasurements`**, with a little additional processing, provides evertything we need -- vertices, edges, vertex coordinates:

```
vertices =  ComponentMeasurements[mtrx2, "Label"][[All,1]];
centroids = ComponentMeasurements[mtrx2, "Centroid"];
neighbors = ComponentMeasurements[mtrx2, "Neighbors"];
edges = UndirectedEdge @@@DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Flatten[Thread /@ neighbors]];

Graph[vertices, edges, VertexCoordinates -> centroids]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[arrayGraph];
arrayGraph[mat_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{m = Module[{i = 1}, mat /. 1 :> i++], edges, vcs, v},
  v = ComponentMeasurements[m, "Label"][[All, 1]];
  vcs = ComponentMeasurements[m, "Centroid"];
  edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ 
    DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Flatten[Thread /@ ComponentMeasurements[m, "Neighbors"]]];
 Graph[v, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcs, opts]]

Show[ArrayPlot[mtrx], 
     arrayGraph[mtrx, VertexSize -> .3, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]]
```

[image]

```
m2 = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {20, 20}];
Show[ArrayPlot[m2], arrayGraph[m2, EdgeStyle -> Yellow]]
```

[image]

```
mat = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {24, 10, 10}];
Grid[Partition[
       arrayGraph[#, ImageSize -> 120, VertexSize -> .4,
          EdgeStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Hue[RandomReal[]]}]] & /@ mat, 6],
  Background -> Black]
```

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant! :)

Comment: @kguler - concerning the 2nd part of your answer (starting with `ClearAll[arrayGraph];` I don't see any lines between the points. Maybe my display shipwrecked? Aside from this: Impressive!

Comment: @eldo, thank you. Do you mean the image after `Show[ArrayPlot[mtrx], arrayGraph[mtrx]]`  or the last image?

Comment: @kguler - Yes, I see blue lines and points looking at Öska's answer, but I don't see the lines in your answer. This blue on black is difficult to see anyway.-

Comment: @eldo, updated with an image with thicker edges.

Comment: @kguler - Now I can see.

Comment: @kguler...very nice...centroids and neighbours just what was needed...always learning

Answer (score 8):

Using old-school `GraphPlot`:

*Edit: the comments that broke the code have been removed*.

```
input =
 {{0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0},
  {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0},
  {0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
  {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},
  {0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0}};

new = Module[{i = 1}, input /. 1 :> i++];

Developer`PartitionMap[Union @@ # &, %, {2, 2}, 1];

Union @@ DeleteCases[%, 0, {-1}];

Union @@ (Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ %);

GraphPlot[Rule @@@ %,
  VertexCoordinateRules -> Reverse[Most @ ArrayRules[new], 2]
]
```

[image]

Operations by line are:

- renumber elements
- find neighbors
- get rid of zeros and duplicates
- convert to neighboring pairs
- plot

Answer (score 6):

Just another answer (not very efficient):

```
vis[m_] := Module[{n, gr},
  n = SparseArray[m]["NonzeroPositions"];
  gr = Union[
    UndirectedEdge @@@ (Sort /@ 
       Flatten[Map[
         Function[u, 
          Thread[{w[u], 
            w /@ (Pick[n, 
               Or[Abs[u - #] == {1, 0}, Abs[u - #] == {0, 1}, 
                  Abs[u - #] == {1, 1}] & /@ n])}]], n], 1])];
  Graph[w /@ n, gr, VertexCoordinates -> ({#2, -#1} & @@@ n)]]
```

Using test matrix:

```
test = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}};
```

then

```
vis[test]
```

[image]

Some random small tests:

```
mat = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {30, 10, 10}];
GraphicsRow[{ArrayPlot[#], vis[#]}] & /@ mat
```

and visualizing:

[image]

Comment: +1! I'm going to steal your `({#2, -#1} & @@@ n)` if you don't mind.. :)

Comment: @Öskå just my lazy way of dealing with coordinates...so feel free...have+1 your neat answer

Answer (score 2):

In this answer the goal is simply to build an adjancy matrix first, that gives you all the information about the graph. The great thing about the code is that you can change how the matrix is connected. For example, in your case you want diagonal components to be connected, here you can change to have only diagonal, only lateral or both. 
At the moment, is simply set by hand. If you want self connections then one can simply replace the array of positions

```
{#[[1,1]],....,#[[3,3]]}
```

with

```
Flatten[#]
```

Otherwise this should allow you to generate the adjancy matrix.

```
myadjancyMatrixforcrystalC[crystal_] := 
     Module[{list = crystal, positions, newcrystal},
             positions = Position[list, 1];
      newcrystal = 
                SparseArray[# -> Range[Length[#]], Dimensions[list], 0] &[positions];
      Return[Map[DeleteCases[#,0] &, 
      {#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], #[[1, 3]], #[[2, 1]], #[[2, 3]], #[[3, 1]], #[[3, 2]], #[[3, 3]]} & /@ (Function[{y}, 
      Take[ArrayPad[newcrystal,1], ##]&@@((# + {1, 1} + {-1, +1}) & /@ y)] /@ positions)]];
      ];
```

since I was dealing with huge matrixes at the time I wrote it, everything was kept as SparseMatrices, but it may not make much of a difference.
Also I don't keep track of the positions of the points, but one could easily return that as part of the code too, to have a graph that can be overlaid over the matrix as some of the other answers, I might add that later.

Here is a small code to takes that adjancy matrix and generates undirected edges.

```
 myedges[adj_] := Module[{myadj = adj},
    Return[
      DeleteDuplicates[
       Sort /@ Flatten[
     MapIndexed[UndirectedEdge[First@#2, #1] &, myadj, {2}]]]];
  ];
```

And the graph for your matrix then is simply.

```
  Graph[myedges[
       myadjancyMatrixforcrystalC[
       {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
        {0, 1, 0, 0,1, 0, 1, 0}, 
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}}]]]
```

Since I didn't keep track of the positions it leads to the same topological graph.

[image]

As I mentioned you can also keep track of the positions in the first part of the code,

```
 myadjancyMatrixforcrystalC[crystal_] := 
     Module[{list = crystal, positions, newcrystal},
      positions = Position[list, 1];


 newcrystal = 
   SparseArray[# -> Range[Length[#]], Dimensions[list], 0] &[
    positions];

  Return[{Map[
    DeleteCases[#,0] &, {#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], #[[1, 3]], #[[2, 1]], #[[2, 
       3]], #[[3, 1]], #[[3, 2]], #[[3, 3]]} & /@ (Function[{y}, 
      Take[ArrayPad[newcrystal, 
          1], ##] & @@ ((# + {1, 1} + {-1, +1}) & /@ y)] /@ 
     positions)], 
 Rule @@@ 
    Thread[{Range[Length[#]], #}] &@({1, -1}*# & /@ (Reverse /@ 
      positions))}];
 ];
```

Now the module `myadjancyMatrixforcrystalC` returns `{adjancy_matrix,vertex->posisionts}` , where the second component is given above by

```
 Rule@@@ 
    Thread[{Range[Length[#]], #}] &@({1, -1}*#&/@(Reverse /@ 
      positions))
```

which is simply vertexid->position, the rest of the math is simply due to the fact `Position` measures the upper left matrix location as `{1,1}` and increases as we go to further rows and columns, and therefore matches with results from say `ArrayPlot`

The positions can be added as option in Graph.

```
Graph[myedges[#[[1]]], VertexCoordinates -> #[[2]]] &[
  myadjancyMatrixforcrystalC[{{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0,
 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
mat = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}}; 


pos = SparseArray[mat]["NonzeroPositions"];
NearestNeighborGraph[pos, DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance, 
 VertexCoordinates -> RotationTransform[-Pi/2]@pos]
```

[image]