# distance between each vertex of a graph and its output

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a question regarding [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50363/graph-from-binary-matrix-not-adjacency-respecting-the-original-matrix-position).

Let's call a vertex that is not the tail of any directed edge an *output* of the graph.
The graph below has only one output (at the far right).
If I want the distance from each vertex to the output of the graph, what should I do?

This one is on my graph:

```
matOP = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
         {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}};

pos = Position[matOP, 1];
edge = Subsets[Range@Length@pos, {2}];
dedge = DeleteDuplicates[
   DirectedEdge @@@ (Extract[edge, #] & /@ 
      With[{dist = 
         N@(EuclideanDistance[pos[[#]], pos[[#2]]] & @@@ edge)}, 
       Flatten[Position[dist, #] & /@ 
         DeleteDuplicates@N@Select[dist, # <= 1.5 &]]])];

Graph[dedge, 
  VertexCoordinates -> Rule @@@ Thread[{Range@Length@pos, pos}]]
```

[image]

Comment: The code you are showing seems to be from @Öskå´s answer in the linked thread, and you should attribute it accordingly.

Comment: @YvesKlett I edited with the link.. :) I guess it's "enough"

Comment: @Öskå in any case, is the Q clear to you?

Comment: @YvesKlett Apart from what I already commented above.., I don't see what could be the answer :)

Comment: Do you mean you want a function that computes the number of edges of the shortest path from any vertex to the final vertex (at the far right)?  If so, look at `FindShortestPath`.

Comment: Yes, Michael, I would like to do this. I tried with FindShortestPath, but I was not able to do it.

Comment: @user15850 could you give us sample code you tried with FindShortestPath ?

Comment: Try `With[{spFN = 
    FindShortestPath[gr, All, 
     First@DeleteCases[Sort@VertexList[gr], 
       n_ /; MemberQ[EdgeList[gr], n \[DirectedEdge] _]]]},
  dist[v_] := Length[spFN[v]] - 1
  ]`, where `gr` is your graph.
Test with
`GraphPlot[gr, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], White, Disk[#1, 0.15], 
     Black, Text[dist@VertexList[gr][[#2]], #1]} &)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the OP's definitions:

```
gr = Graph[dedge, VertexCoordinates -> Rule @@@ Thread[{Range@Length@pos, pos}]]

With[{spFN = FindShortestPath[gr, All, 
     First @ DeleteCases[Sort@VertexList[gr], 
       n_ /; MemberQ[EdgeList[gr], n \[DirectedEdge] _]]]},
  dist[v_] := Length[spFN[v]] - 1
  ];
```

Then `dist[v]` gives the number of edges between `v` and the output vertex, which is found by the code

```
First@DeleteCases[Sort@VertexList[gr], 
  n_ /; MemberQ[EdgeList[gr], n \[DirectedEdge] _]]
```

One could check that there is only one output vertex, but it is clearly the case for the OP's graph.

Here's a visualization:  Each vertex is labelled by its distance to the output vertex.

```
GraphPlot[gr, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], White, Disk[#1, 0.15], 
     Black, Text[dist@VertexList[gr][[#2]], #1]} &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: if I wanted to bring back the values ​​of the distances in the original matrix, substituting the values ​​of 1, how should I do?

Comment: @user15850 Is this what you seek?: `ReplacePart[matOP, MapIndexed[#1 -> dist[First@#2] &, pos]]`

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @user15850 You're welcome.