# Connect neighbouring points as list of segments in 2 D

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, topology

### Context

I am interested in connecting neighboring points in 2/3D as list of segments.
I am guessing this is something within the reach of graph theory, 
which is well implemented in mathematica.

### Problem

To be more specific, let me consider connecting together points 
which correspond to critical lines in 2D.

Starting from a [GaussianRandomField](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4916/1089)

```
u = GaussianRandomField[n = 128*2, 2, Function[k, 1/k Exp[-1/40 k^2]]] // Chop;
```

I can identify the 2D skeleton (the 'ridges' of the density field see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9928/1089) or that [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20910/1089)) as

```
 skl = Map[If[# == 0, 1, 0] &, -u // Image // WatershedComponents, {2}] // SparseArray; 
 HighlightImage[ReliefImage[-u // Image, ColorFunction -> ColorData["ThermometerColors"]],
 skl // Image, "HighlightColor" -> Yellow]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

follow [this link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/659996/skl.m)  to upload an example of such skeleton.

For instance, looking at a small subset of the table I would have

```
 skl[[Range[15], Range[15]]] // Normal // MatrixPlot
```

So `skl` contains zeros and ones wherever that pixel lies on a ridge.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can then extract the coordinates of all points on the skeleton

```
 pos = skl // ArrayRules // Most // Map[First, #] & // Sort;
```

Indeed, they correspond to the same skeleton

```
 Reverse[#*{-1, 1}] & /@ pos // ListPlot[#, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In practice it is useful to know which points on the skeleton are connected to which.

### Question

> > I would like to join all neighbouring points of the skeleton as segments. Ideally I would like to tag each segment with a label keeping track of which branch of the skeleton it belongs to.

### Attempt

Using the function [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Nearest.html) I have tried

```
 nf = Nearest[pos];
 tt = Map[nf[#, 4] &, pos, 1];
 tt2 = Select[tt, Norm[((# - Table[#[[1]], {4}]))] < 3 &];
 gr = Map[Line[{Rest[#], Table[#[[1]], {Length[#] - 1}]} // Transpose] &, tt2] // Graphics;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> which seems to do the trick but there might be more *efficient/robust* way to proceed?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17955/discussion-on-question-by-chris-connect-neighbouring-points-as-list-of-segments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Oska noted in the comments, adding the option `CornerNeighbors->False` in [arrayGraph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50453/1089) gives the desired result for `2D`. (See also [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51284/125) to a different Q/A)..

```
ClearAll[arrayGraph];
arrayGraph[mat_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{m = Module[{i = 1}, mat /. 1 :> i++], edges, vcs, v}, 
  v = ComponentMeasurements[m, "Label"][[All, 1]];
  vcs = ComponentMeasurements[m, "Centroid"];
  edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Flatten[Thread /@ 
        ComponentMeasurements[m, "Neighbors", CornerNeighbors -> False]]];
  Graph[v, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcs, opts]]

arrayGraph[Normal@skl, VertexSize -> .3, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], ImageSize -> 650]
```

[image]