# Why Is Finding Minimal Bounding Box Using ComponentMeasurements So Slow?

Tags: image-processing, image

My goal is to find the coordinates of the minimal bounding box for this image.

[image: Binary Image]

I am using the following command:

```
ComponentMeasurements[img, "MinimalBoundingBox"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

The output is the following:

```
{5.31663, {1 -> {{338.492, 1064.99}, {156.654, 
 71.8802}, {1084.66, -98.0355}, {1266.49, 895.079}}}}
```

Why does this computation take so long?  It seems that `ImageCrop` can perform a similar computation and crop the image but it does so much much faster.  Am I just using `ComponentMeasurements` innapropriately or is there something else I am missing?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: If you can do it with `ImageCrop` then `ComponentMeasurements` is overkill, yes. It's doing something like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51612/731), to find the components, and that's more complicated than finding max and minimum coordinates of all components combined.

Comment: My problem with `ImageCrop` is that it doesn't return the coordinates you would use from the original image to give the minimal bounding box.

Comment: ok, it makes more sense now but I just realized that `MinimalBoundingBox` returns an oriented bounding box, which is another important difference from `ImageCrop`. If it were just an axes-oriented bounding box then a good start might have been `MinMax /@ Transpose[SparseArray[ImageData[img]]["NonzeroPositions"]]`. Finding an oriented bounding box is more complicated.

Comment: You could use `ComponentMeasurements[img, "BoundingBox"]` if you just want the axis-oriented bounding box. That's much faster

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ComponentMeasurements[img, "MinimalBoundingBox"]` finds the smallest bounding box *in any orientation*, which is a more complex problem than what `ImageCrop` solves:

```
pts = ComponentMeasurements[img, "MinimalBoundingBox"][[1, 2]];
HighlightImage[img, Polygon[pts]]
```

[image]

If that's what you need, you can make it a little faster by passing only the perimeter to `ComponentMeasurements`, so it has to check fewer pixels:

```
ComponentMeasurements[
 MorphologicalPerimeter@img, "MinimalBoundingBox"]
```

runs about 20x faster on my PC and gives the same bounding box. (At least unless your objects have holes!)

If you're only interested in the axis-aligned bounding box, use `ComponentMeasurements[img, "BoundingBox"]` instead:

```
b = ComponentMeasurements[img, "BoundingBox"][[1, 2]];
HighlightImage[img, Rectangle @@ b]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I should've noticed there was a `MinimalBoundingBox` and a `BoundingBox`!  This makes more sense.