# How to build a 3D graph from a 3D matrix?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, graphics3d

Following [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50363/1089)
 and [that question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61852/1089)
and the corresponding answers, Mathematica can build 2D graph from 2D matrices.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Question

> How to make the corresponding 3D graphs from 3D cubes?

### Attempt

Modifying ever so slightly this great 2D [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50453/1089) from @kguler

```
ClearAll[arrayGraph];
arrayGraph[mat_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
Module[{m = Module[{i = 1}, mat /. 1 :> i++], edges, vcs, v}, 
v = ComponentMeasurements[m, "Label"][[All, 1]];
vcs = ComponentMeasurements[m, "Centroid"];
edges = 
UndirectedEdge @@@ 
DeleteDuplicates[
 Sort /@ Flatten[Thread /@ ComponentMeasurements[m, "Neighbors"]]];
Graph3D[v, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcs, opts]]
```

Then I get

```
 mat = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {3, 3, 3}];
 arrayGraph[mat, VertexSize -> .3, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], Boxed -> True]
```

producing the following funky plot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which nicely shows how the three planes are not connected.

Comment: chris, can you try with the following modification of `arrayGraph`: add before the last line `edges2= UndirectedEdge @@@ 
DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Flatten[Thread /@ ComponentMeasurements[Transpose/@m, "Neighbors"]]];edges=DeleteDuplicates[Join[edges,edges2]];` (I am using the free online version of V10, and the input matrix is too large given the limitations of the free version.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `ComponentMeasurements` twice, on the original matrix `m` and on `Transpose/@m` we can get all `Neighbors`:

```
mat = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {3, 3, 3}];
m = Module[{i = 1}, mat /. 1 :> i++];

v = ComponentMeasurements[m, "Label"][[All, 1]]
```

> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}

```
vcoords = ComponentMeasurements[m, "Centroid"][[All, -1]]
```

> {{0.5,2.5,2.5},{1.5,2.5,2.5},{0.5,1.5,2.5},{1.5,1.5,2.5},{0.5,0.5,2. 5},
>          {2.5,0.5,2.5},{2.5,2.5,1.5},{0.5,1.5,1.5},{0.5,0.5,1.5},{1.5,0.5,1. 5},
>          {1.5,2.5,0.5},{2.5,2.5,0.5},{2.5,1.5,0.5},{1.5,0.5,0.5}}

```
linksa = List @@@ DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Flatten[Thread /@ 
   ComponentMeasurements[m, "Neighbors", CornerNeighbors -> False]]]
```

> {{1,3},{2,4},{3,5},{3,8},{5,9},{7,12},{8,9},{10,14},{12,13}}

```
linksb = List @@@ DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Flatten[Thread /@ 
  ComponentMeasurements[Transpose /@ m, "Neighbors", CornerNeighbors -> False]]]
```

> {{1,2},{3,4},{3,8},{5,9},{7,12},{9,10},{10,14},{11,12}}

```
alllinks = DeleteDuplicates[Join[linksa, linksb]]
```

> {{1,3},{2,4},{3,5},{3,8},{5,9},{7,12},{8,9},{10,14},{12,13},{1,2},{3,4},{9,10},{11,12}}

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[vcoords, {PointSize[Large], Red, 
   Sphere[#, .1] & /@ v, Thick, Blue, Line[alllinks]}]]
```

[image]

**Update:** a larger input matrix

```
mat = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10, 10, 10}];

(* ... same calculations for v, vcoords and alllinks as above *)

Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[vcoords, {PointSize[Large],
   Red, Sphere[#, .15] & /@ v, Opacity[.7], Orange, Tube[alllinks]}],
 ImageSize -> 500, Background -> Black, Boxed -> False]
```

we get

[image]

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[vcoords,
 {PointSize[Large], Red, Sphere[#, .15] & /@ v, 
  Opacity[.1], White, Cuboid[vcoords[[#]] - .5, vcoords[[#]] + .5] & /@ v,
  Opacity[.9], Orange, Tube[alllinks]}],
 ImageSize -> 500, Background -> Black, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

**Note:** Had to use `Graphics3D` to produce the output instead of `Graph3D` 
because somehow

```
Graph3D[UndirectedEdge@@@alllinks, VertexCoordinates->Thread[v->vcoords]]
```

gives `Null` on the free version of `Wolfram Programming Cloud`.

### Update

This can be encapsulated as follows

```
ClearAll[arrayGraph];
arrayGraph[mat_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
Module[{m = Module[{i = 1}, mat /. 1 :> i++], edges, edges2, vcs, v},
v = ComponentMeasurements[m, "Label"][[All, 1]];
vcs = ComponentMeasurements[m, "Centroid"];
edges = 
UndirectedEdge @@@ 
DeleteDuplicates[
 Sort /@ Flatten[Thread /@ ComponentMeasurements[m, "Neighbors",
     FilterRules[Flatten[{opts}], 
      Options[ComponentMeasurements]]]]];
edges2 = 
UndirectedEdge @@@ 
DeleteDuplicates[
 Sort /@ Flatten[
   Thread /@ ComponentMeasurements[Transpose /@ m, "Neighbors",
     FilterRules[Flatten[{opts}], 
      Options[ComponentMeasurements]]]]]; 
edges = DeleteDuplicates[Join[edges, edges2]];
Graph3D[v, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcs, 
FilterRules[Flatten[{opts}], Options[Graph3D]]]]
```

which works as follows:

```
 mat = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {3, 3, 3}];
 arrayGraph[mat, VertexSize -> .3, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
 Boxed -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And if diagonal links are not required,

```
 arrayGraph[mat, VertexSize -> .3, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
 Boxed -> True, CornerNeighbors-> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It works also on the skeletons

```
 (pl = {(skl = skel[dat]) // Image3D[#, ImageSize -> 300] & // 
 Rasterize,Image[arrayGraph[skl // Normal, CornerNeighbors -> False], 
 ImageSize -> 300]}); ImageMultiply@@pl
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I knew that you would come out with something funky, +1!

Comment: thank you @Oska. Got lucky here, V10 happened to add to `ComponentMeasurements` just what we needed for this question:)

Answer (score 10):

Here is how it works. If you have a volume in 3d it is essential, that you use connected component labeling in 3d so that components that are connected over layers stick together and get the same label. Lucky for us that `MorphologicalComponents` can do this. Let's create a test volume

```
data = With[{init = RandomChoice[{0, 0, 1}, {10, 10}]},
   NestList[
    If[RandomChoice[{True, True, False}], 
      RotateLeft /@ #, #*Transpose[#]] &, init, 9]
   ];
cmp = MorphologicalComponents[data, 
  CornerNeighbors -> False]; 
Colorize[cmp]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The colors indicate that objects are correctly recognized throughout the layers. Note that I used the $N_6$-foreground neighborhood here because this is a bit more intuitive when watching a 3d volume.

What you need to do now is to extract all voxel positions a label that are directly connected within the component. This can be done by simply checking `Norm[Subtract[p1,p2]]===1`. With `Outer` I compare all position combinations and create edges for directly neighboring positions. Note that if I would need to implement this fast, this is not the way to go.

With these edges I create a temporary `Graph3D` for one component. I use this to extract the correctly sorted `VertexList` which I need later to set the `VertexCoordinates` correctly. This all is done in the following function

```
builtGraph[components_, label_] :=
 Module[{g},
  g = Graph3D[
    DeleteDuplicates@
     Flatten@Last@Reap@Block[{labelOnly = Position[components, label]},
         Outer[
          If[Norm[Subtract[##]] === 1, 
            Sow[UndirectedEdge @@ Sort[{##}]]] &, labelOnly, 
          labelOnly, 1]
         ]];
  {EdgeList[g], VertexList[g]}
  ]
```

After that, I need to apply this function to each component label in the volume and built a final graph from it. Combining the single edge- and vertex-lists is a bit playing with `Transpose` and `Flatten`, but nothing really hard. The rest is simple

```
Graph3D[#1, VertexCoordinates -> #2] & @@ (Flatten[#, 1] & /@ 
   Transpose@Table[builtGraph[cmp, i], {i, Max[Flatten[cmp]]}])
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

If you look close, you see the stair-structure on the right which is on the left in the image above and the green upside-down "T" of the image is in the upper left corner of the graph. This comes from `Position` which reverses the position in the matrix, but I'm sure you can fix this yourself.

One final note, since I was extracting edges rather than vertices and I haven't allowed self-referencing edges, you won't find components in the graph which consist only of one voxel.

Comment: Nice answer too; sorry I could not accept both!

Answer (score 4):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) makes this really easy using its mesh/graph conversion functions along with [`ArrayMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayMesh.html).

Here's an array:

```
SeedRandom[42]
arr = RandomInteger[1, {8, 8, 8}];
```

Make a mesh:

```
mesh = ArrayMesh[arr]
```

[image]

Construct the adjacency graph of 3D cells:

```
IGMeshCellAdjacencyGraph[ArrayMesh[arr], 3]
```

We can add vertex coordinates manually, if needed:

```
IGMeshCellAdjacencyGraph[mesh, 3, 
 VertexCoordinates -> PropertyValue[{mesh, 3}, MeshCellCentroid]]
```

[image]

This graph connects cells with a common adjacent face (von Neumann neighbourhood). If instead you want to connect cells with a common adjacent edge (1-dimensional cell), you can do this:

```
mat = IGMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[mesh, 3, 1];

SimpleGraph[
 AdjacencyGraph@Unitize[mat.Transpose[mat]],
 VertexCoordinates -> PropertyValue[{mesh, 3}, MeshCellCentroid]
]
```

[image]

Or perhaps you want to connect cells with a common vertex (0-dimensional cell), i.e. also include the diagonals of the cubes as connections.

[image]

---

You can also use `IGBipartiteProjections` to get the same graph like this:

```
SetProperty[
 First@IGBipartiteProjections@IGMeshCellAdjacencyGraph[mesh, 3, 1],
 VertexCoordinates -> PropertyValue[{mesh, 3}, MeshCellCentroid]
]
```

This last solution is a bit sloppy because it determines the bipartite partitions automatically, and there is more than one valid partitioning. A robust way is to specify partitions manually:

```
SetProperty[
 First@IGBipartiteProjections[IGMeshCellAdjacencyGraph[mesh, 3, 1], {MeshCellIndex[mesh, 3], MeshCellIndex[mesh, 1]}],
 VertexCoordinates -> PropertyValue[{mesh, 3}, MeshCellCentroid]
]
```

Some background:

`IGMeshCellAdjacencyGraph[mesh, 3, 1]` gives the bipartite graph describing the connectivity of dimension-3 and dimension-1 mesh cells.  A bipartite graph is a graph with two groups of vertices, $A$ and $B$, where connections may only run between the two groups (but not within a single group).  A bipartite projection is a graph whose vertex set is $A$, and two of its vertices $a_1, a_2 \in A$ are connected iff there is some vertex $b \in B$ so that the connections $a_1 \leftrightarrow b$ and $a_2 \leftrightarrow b$ both exist.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative solution with [`RelationGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html).

Here's an array:

```
SeedRandom[42]
arr = RandomInteger[1, {8, 8, 8}];

Image3D[arr]
```

[image]

Take the coordinates of the marked cells:

```
pts = Keys@Most@ArrayRules[arr];
```

Connect points whose distance is no larger than $\sqrt{3}$, then remove self-connection with [`SimpleGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SimpleGraph.html).

```
SimpleGraph[
 RelationGraph[Norm[#1 - #2] <= Sqrt[3] &, pts],
 VertexCoordinates -> pts
]
```

[image]

If you only want connections through a common edge or face (instead of a common corner point), use $\sqrt{2}$ or $1$ as the distance threshold.

This solution is quite slow (much slow than the other one I posted), but it is by far the simplest.